# Merge python dictionaries with common key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Assume I have the following dictionaries:

```
{name: "john", place: "nyc", owns: "gold", quantity: 30}
{name: "john", place: "nyc", owns: "silver", quantity: 20}
{name: "jane", place: "nyc", owns: "platinum", quantity: 5}
{name: "john", place: "chicago", owns: "brass", quantity: 60}
{name: "john", place: "chicago", owns: "silver", quantity: 40}
```

And I have hundreds of these small dictionaries. I have to merge them with a subset of common keys, in this example (name, place) and create a new dictionary. Ultimately, the output should look like the following:

```
{name: "john", place: "nyc", gold: 30, silver: 20}
{name: "jane", place: "nyc", platinum: 5}
{name: "john", place: "chicago", brass: 60, silver: 40}
```

Is there any efficient way to do this? All I can think of is brute-force, where I will keep track of every possible name-place combination, store in some list, traverse the entire thing again for each combination and merge the dictionaries into a new one. Thanks!

Comment: *two dictionaries*; I counted 5

Comment: sorry, i have fixed it now.

Comment: Don't think it's a duplicate of that question: the merging strategy is more complicated.

Comment: The result you want is a **denormalization** of the data and is guaranteed to make it harder to work with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, getting the output that you asked for:

```
data = [{'name': "john", 'place': "nyc", 'owns': "gold", 'quantity': 30},
{'name': "john", 'place': "nyc", 'owns': "silver", 'quantity': 20},
{'name': "jane", 'place': "nyc", 'owns': "platinum", 'quantity': 5},
{'name': "john", 'place': "chicago", 'owns': "brass", 'quantity': 60},
{'name': "john", 'place': "chicago", 'owns': "silver", 'quantity': 40}]

from collections import defaultdict

accumulator = defaultdict(list)

for p in data:
    accumulator[p['name'],p['place']].append((p['owns'],p['quantity']))

from itertools import chain

[dict(chain([('name',name), ('place',place)], rest)) for (name,place),rest in accumulator.iteritems()]
Out[13]: 
[{'name': 'jane', 'place': 'nyc', 'platinum': 5},
 {'brass': 60, 'name': 'john', 'place': 'chicago', 'silver': 40},
 {'gold': 30, 'name': 'john', 'place': 'nyc', 'silver': 20}]
```

Now I **have** to point out that this list-of-dicts data structure you've asked for is super awkward.  Dicts are great for *lookups*, but they perform best when you can just use *one* for the whole group of objects - if you have to linearly search through a bunch of dicts to find the one you want, you've immediately lost the whole benefit that `dict` provides in the first place.  So that leaves us with a couple of options.  Go one level deeper - nest `dict`s within our `dict`, or use something else entirely.

May I suggest making a list of meaningful objects which each represent one of these people?  Either create your own `class`, or use a `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple('Person','name place holdings')

[Person(name, place, dict(rest)) for (name,place), rest in accumulator.iteritems()]
Out[17]: 
[Person(name='jane', place='nyc', holdings={'platinum': 5}),
 Person(name='john', place='chicago', holdings={'brass': 60, 'silver': 40}),
 Person(name='john', place='nyc', holdings={'silver': 20, 'gold': 30})]
```

Answer (score 1):

So my personal strategy for this is roughly outlined below. You should define a key generator given an instance of a dict, and then group it in an isolated dict by that key generated. Once you've iterated through all elements and updated based on the key, then simply return the `.values()` of the grouped dict.

```
dicts = [
    {"name": "john", "place": "nyc", "owns": "gold", "quantity": 30},
    {"name": "john", "place": "nyc", "owns": "silver", "quantity": 20},
    {"name": "jane", "place": "nyc", "owns": "platinum", "quantity": 5},
    {"name": "john", "place": "chicago", "owns": "brass", "quantity": 60},
    {"name": "john", "place": "chicago", "owns": "silver", "quantity": 40}
]

def get_key(instance):
    return "%s-%s" % (instance.get("name"), instance.get("place"), )

grouped = {}

for dict_ in dicts:
    grouped[get_key(dict_)] = grouped.get(get_key(dict_), {})
    grouped[get_key(dict_)].update(dict_)

print grouped.values()
# [
#   {'owns': 'platinum', 'place': 'nyc', 'name': 'jane', 'quantity': 5},
#   {'name': 'john', 'place': 'nyc', 'owns': 'silver', 'quantity': 20}, 
#   {'name': 'john', 'place': 'chicago', 'owns': 'silver', 'quantity': 40}
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a crazy idea, but how about a dict-of-dicts-of-dicts? This would work like a 2D array, the row and column indices being the names and places.

```
my_dicts = [
    {"name": "john", "place": "nyc", "owns": "gold", "quantity": 30},
    {"name": "john", "place": "nyc", "owns": "silver", "quantity": 20},
    {"name": "jane", "place": "nyc", "owns": "platinum", "quantity": 5},
    {"name": "john", "place": "chicago", "owns": "brass", "quantity": 60},
    {"name": "john", "place": "chicago", "owns": "silver", "quantity": 40}
]

all_names = set(d["name"] for d in my_dicts)
all_places = set(d["place"] for d in my_dicts)

merged = {name : {place : {} for place in all_places} for name in all_names}

for d in my_dicts:
    merged[d["name"]][d["place"]][d["owns"]] = d["quantity"]

import pprint
pprint.pprint(merged)

# {'jane': {'chicago': {}, 'nyc': {'platinum': 5}},
#  'john': {'chicago': {'brass': 60, 'silver': 40},
#           'nyc': {'gold': 30, 'silver': 20}}}
```

Then convert to your desired format:

```
new_dicts = [{"name" : name, "place" : place} for name in all_names for place in all_places if merged[name][place]]
for d in new_dicts:
    d.update(merged[d["name"]][d["place"]])
pprint.pprint(new_dicts)

# [{'name': 'jane', 'place': 'nyc', 'platinum': 5},
#  {'gold': 30, 'name': 'john', 'place': 'nyc', 'silver': 20},
#  {'brass': 60, 'name': 'john', 'place': 'chicago', 'silver': 40}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby
result, get_owns = [], lambda x: x["owns"]
get_details =  lambda x: (x["name"], x["place"])

# Sort and group the data based on name and place
for key, grp in groupby(sorted(data, key=get_details), key=get_details):

    # Create a dictionary with the name and place
    temp = dict(zip(("name", "place"), key))

    # Sort and group the grouped data based on owns
    for owns, grp1 in groupby(sorted(grp, key=get_owns), key=get_owns):

        # For each material, find and add the sum of quantity in temp
        temp[owns] = sum(item["quantity"] for item in grp1)

    # Add the temp dictionary to the result :-)
    result.append(temp)
print result
```

**Output**

```
[{'name': 'jane', 'place': 'nyc', 'platinum': 5},
 {'brass': 60, 'name': 'john', 'place': 'chicago', 'silver': 40},
 {'gold': 30, 'name': 'john', 'place': 'nyc', 'silver': 20}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
dicts = [
    {"name": "john", "place": "nyc", "owns": "gold", "quantity": 30},
    {"name": "john", "place": "nyc", "owns": "silver", "quantity": 20},
    {"name": "jane", "place": "nyc", "owns": "platinum", "quantity": 5},
    {"name": "john", "place": "chicago", "owns": "brass", "quantity": 60},
    {"name": "john", "place": "chicago", "owns": "silver", "quantity": 40}
]
```

We create a transformed dict with `place-name` as key and output dict as the value

```
transformed_dict = {}
for a_dict in dicts:
    key = '{}-{}'.format(a_dict['place'], a_dict['name'])
    if key not in transformed_dict:
        transformed_dict[key] = {'name': a_dict['name'], 'place': a_dict['place'], a_dict['owns']: a_dict['quantity']}
    else:
        transformed_dict[key][a_dict['owns']] = a_dict['quantity']
```

`transformed_dict` now looks like:

```
{'chicago-john': {'brass': 60,
                  'name': 'john',
                  'place': 'chicago',
                  'silver': 40},
 'nyc-jane': {'name': 'jane', 'place': 'nyc', 'platinum': 5},
 'nyc-john': {'gold': 30, 'name': 'john', 'place': 'nyc', 'silver': 20}}
```

`pprint(list(transformed_dict.values()))` gives what we want:

```
[{'gold': 30, 'name': 'john', 'place': 'nyc', 'silver': 20},
 {'brass': 60, 'name': 'john', 'place': 'chicago', 'silver': 40},
 {'name': 'jane', 'place': 'nyc', 'platinum': 5}]
```